# views output file alterations

Tags: 7, views

I am using d7 and views.

I've created a view tpl file specific to my view using the the file name of: `views-view-fields--cameras.tpl.php`

```
<?php 

foreach ($fields as $id => $field): ?>
<?php 
$output = '';
$output .=  $field->label_html;
$output .= '<table width=100% border=1>';
if($field->label_html == 'camera_brand_star:')
{
$output .= $field->wrapper_prefix;
$output .= '<tr><td>hello</td></tr>';
$output .= $field->wrapper_suffix;
}
else if($field->label_html == 'camera_price_star')
{
$output .= $field->wrapper_prefix;
$output .= '<tr><td>'.$field->content.'</td></tr>';
$output .= $field->wrapper_suffix;
}
else if($field->label_html == 'brand:')
{
$output .= $field->wrapper_prefix;
$output .= '<tr><td>'.$field->content.'</td></tr>';
$output .= $field->wrapper_suffix;
}

else
{
$output .= $field->wrapper_prefix;
//$output .= '<tr><td>'.$field->content.'</td></tr>';
$output .= $field->wrapper_suffix;
}
$output .= '</table>';
echo $output;
//echo $field->label_html;
?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The if conditions are not working at all as its not printing any content. Only it prints the output of     `$output .=  $field->label_html;`   What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide the markup that's currently produced by this code. The PHP logic looks fine but it's not cleat if `$field->label_html` has a value that will trigger and of the if statements. As a bare minimum you should be getting:

```
<table width=100% border=1>
</table>
```